# On iPad, how do i change the content of one UITableView based on a selected Cell from another?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I am having a lot of trouble working with these Tables. I am porting an iPhone app over to the iPad. I have two UITableViews on the iPad, each with their own Controller. On the iPhone, these tables each have their own screen. When you get to the first table (a list of categories), you select a row, and then a push segue brings you to the second table (all of the items that pertain to that specific category). However, on the iPad, I cannot get the second table to update when a cell is selected from the first table. I cannot reloadData because I am having trouble telling the 2nd table what category was picked from the 1st table.

Some good news: Both tables show up on the root view controller (UIViewController). Table 1 shows all of it's categories, and table 2 shows all of the items from the first category from viewDidLoad (I programmed it to display the first set of items to ensure that it was at least working).

So my question is the line in the title, how do I change the content of the 2nd table based on which cell is selected from the first?

EDIT: I have more than just 2 tables on this one iPad view. I tried to post an image, but can't yet.. There are 4 table views, a custom Banner ad imageview, and some labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is a standard master-detail interface. I guess the detail view controller has a property defined in the .h file where you can set the new 'detail item'. If not, you need to add one (and you must currently have one in the init method or something).

Implement the setter method for that property, update the detail item and then `reloadData`.

This way you're just updating the existing view controller rather than trying to create a new one each time.

I'd recommend you create a new iPad (or universal) project in Xcode, select the master-detail project template and have a look at the code it contains.

Comment: I have thought about using master-detail, but I actually have more than 2 tables. I have a custom banner ad (UIImageView), an RSS Feed (UITableView), a Calendar that pulls events from a website (UITableView), and then the 2 tables mentioned in the question. I am not sure if the master-detail approach can accomodate for all of my needs.. I just need to find a way to send data (category selected) from one table to the other, and then update the second table.

Comment: master-detail is just a description of the relationship between 2 controllers. It doesn't prohibit other relationships in and around it.

Comment: Can it be used in a UIViewController? If not, can I still display the other 2 tables that are completely separate from the Categories tables? (So, still showing 4 tables simultaneously)

Comment: You could have one view controller which is the windows root view controller and it's a 'container' view controller. You add all the other views as child view controllers and add their views as subviews. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html